# Understanding Pylint E1101: Instance has no replace member

Tags: python, methods, error-handling, pylint

I'm writing a function that return the number of pairs between two strings.  I want to avoid false pairs, so whenever there's a pair, I'm replacing the letters with junk.  However I'm seeing a Pylint E1101 error and I'm unsure what that means or how to resolve it.

Code is here:

```
s1 = 'abca'
s2 = 'xyzbac'

def function(s1, s2):
    t1 = list(s1)
    t2 = list(s2)
    total = 0
    print (t1)
    print (t2)
    for i in t1:
        for j in t2:
            print (i, j)
            if i == j:
                total += 1
                t1.replace(i, 1)
                t2.replace(j, 2)
    return total
print (total)
```

Comment: `list`s have no replace method/attribute

Comment: @zach agostine - as chris mentioned list has no replacement method. so you could change like this, t1[t1.index(i)]= 1 t2[t2.index(j)]= 2

Comment: Thanks @Moharmed, that works. As I am somewhat new to programming, can you explain why this works and my original code doesn't?

Comment: @ZachAgostine Added to solution. accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace element in list:

```
t1[t1.index(i)]= 1 # instead of this t1.replace(i, 1)
t2[t2.index(j)]= 2 # instead of this t2.replace(j, 2)
```

You can't replace list by `replace` method. to replace elements in list above code is one way to solve this.